# Populate Dynamic Input Box with existing Data VueJs

Tags: vue.js, input

From the title itself, I want to populate a dynamically created input box that I will load via AJAX upon page load.

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="app">
   <div class="form-row" v-for="i in travellers"> 
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" v-for="(details, index) in bookingRequiredDetails">
         <label for="required-details">{{ details }}</label>
          <input 
             type="text" 
             class="form-control"
             @input="prop('traveller_' + i, details, $event)"
             placeholder="Required Details" 
           />
     </div>
   </div>
</div>


data () {
   return {
      bookingForm: {
                ...
                bookingRequiredDetails: ''
            },
      travellerDetails: {},
   }
},
load: function () {
      ... where the data variable has value upon page load

      vm.bookingForm.bookingRequiredDetails = data.bookingRequiredDetails;
      if (data.travellerDetails) {
           vm.travellerDetails = data.travellerDetails;
      }
}
```

Loaded Data:

The input boxes generated will depend on the required details. So for this instance, there will be 3 generated input boxes.

```
bookingRequiredDetails: Array(1)
  0: Array(3)
      0: "Full Name"
      1: "Age"
      2: "Gender"

travellerDetails: Array(1)
    0:
      traveller_1: Object
          Age: "12"
          Full Name: "Jane"
          Gender: "M"
    1: ...
    2: ...
```

Sample Output:
[image]

What I want is to populate the existing travellerDetails object with data loaded from the server to their respective input boxes. However, I have problems with pairing the correct data to their respective key-value pairs of the input box as shown in the screenshot.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Transform the data into something more useful to your program, rather than just copying it into things that are hard to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I manage to solve it. By adding v-model.

```
v-model="travellerDetails['traveller_' + i][details]"

div class="col-md-10" id="app">
   <div class="form-row" v-for="i in travellers"> 
      <div class="form-group col-md-6" v-for="(details, index) in bookingRequiredDetails">
         <label for="required-details">{{ details }}</label>
          <input 
             type="text" 
             class="form-control"
             v-model="travellerDetails['traveller_' + i][details]"
             @input="prop('traveller_' + i, details, $event)"
             placeholder="Required Details" 
           />
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: curious...how is Vue data getting populated? facing a similar problem. but i want to load by Vue created model from data that is loaded in the page separately. apparently very difficult as its not yet available when the Vue code is run